# Android: Display ImageView from 2 different sources

Tags: android, imageview

I'm looking to populate an imageview depending on which source contains the data. The holder.imgImage could have either a bitmap source or a drawable path but I only want one to be displayed depending on which image is present. I have tried if (image !=null) but doesnt seeem to work.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.myTextView1.setText(categoryList.get(position).getRecipe_name());
    holder.myTextView2.setText(categoryList.get(position).getCategory_name());
    String image2 = categoryList.get(position).getImage2();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image2);
    holder.imgImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    holder.imgImage.setImageResource(categoryList.get(position).getImage());

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe check if created `Bitmap` isn't `null`?

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image2);
if (myBitmap != null)
    holder.imgImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
else
    holder.imgImage.setImageResource(categoryList.get(position).getImage());
```

maybe there is a case when `getImage2()` returns `null` or empty string?

```
String image2 = categoryList.get(position).getImage2();
Bitmap myBitmap = (image2 != null && image2.length()) > 0 ? 
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image2) : null;
```

Comment: That works however I get this error  E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20200923_103428.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: well, this is another topic and should be another question... do you have proper permission in your manifest? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` note that since Android 6.0 you may have to [ask user for some permissions during runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting), just declaring perm in manifest isn't sufficient